# Implementing interface using child class exception

Tags: java, oop, generics, polymorphism

It is my understanding that a class implementing an interface can use the child classes of a class defined in the interface rather than only being able to use this specific class.

Here's an example of what I mean: Assume the following code

```
public abstract class TestRootAbstractClass implements TestInterface {}
```

and

```
public abstract class TestChildAbstractClass extends TestRootAbstractClass {}
```

The `TestInterface` defined in `TestRootAbstractClass` looks like this

```
public interface TestInterface<T extends TestRootClass> {
    void test(T extendedTestClass) throws Exception;
}
```

and the `TestRootClass` referenced in `TestInterface` looks like this

```
public abstract class TestRootClass {}
```

This class also has a child class that looks like this

```
public class TestChildClass extends TestRootClass {}
```

I would think that the following Java code would be valid due to the generics used in `TestInterface`

```
public class TestImplementation extends TestChildAbstractClass {

    public void test(TestChildClass top) {
        System.out.println("tested");
    }
}
```

but Java complains that

> the abstract method `test(T)` defined in `TestInterface` is not implemented.

Isn't this valid OOP that should work?

Comment: if `T` defaulted to `Object`, then that would be even better for the code that I posted...i would definitely not have the issue. And in `TestInterface`, I actually specify that a valid `T` is `T extends TestRootClass` which should narrow the scope further from `Object`

Comment: I don't see how making `TestImplementation` abstract would solve the issue. If anything, it would "delay" the issue to the first concrete implementation.

Comment: I corrected my initial statement and tried to be more precise in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to specify what `T` is in `public abstract class TestRootAbstractClass implements TestInterface {}`. Therefore `T` defaults to `TestRootClass` which means that `TestImplementation` does not correctly implement the interface `TestChildAbstractClass` because it *only* allows `TestChildClass` parameters, but no other subclasses of `TestRootClass`.

You should either specify it or let the child class of `TestRootAbstractClass` do it. The following does the later, compiling just fine:

```
abstract class TestRootAbstractClass<T extends TestRootClass> implements TestInterface<T> {}

abstract class TestChildAbstractClass<T extends TestRootClass> extends TestRootAbstractClass<T> {}

interface TestInterface<T extends TestRootClass> {
    void test(T extendedTestClass) throws Exception;
}

abstract class TestRootClass {}

class TestChildClass extends TestRootClass {}

class TestImplementation extends TestChildAbstractClass<TestChildClass> {

    public void test(TestChildClass top) {
        System.out.println("tested");
    }
}
```

---

or you change the method in the `TestImplementation` to accept all `TestRootClass`es.

```
abstract class TestRootAbstractClass implements TestInterface {}
abstract class TestChildAbstractClass extends TestRootAbstractClass{}
interface TestInterface<T extends TestRootClass> {
    void test(T extendedTestClass) throws Exception;
}
abstract class TestRootClass {}
class TestChildClass extends TestRootClass {}
class TestImplementation extends TestChildAbstractClass {

    public void test(TestRootClass top) {
        System.out.println("tested");
    }
}
```

But now you can drop the generics all together and just use:

```
interface TestInterface {
    void test(TestRootClass extendedTestClass) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 however the reason I use `public void test(TestChildClass top)` rather than `public void test(TestRootClass top)` is because `TestChildClass` has additional methods that its parent class `TestRootClass` does not have

Comment: @reayn3 okay, then you can and should use the first code block. Note that I am not 100% sure if you might want to move the constraint to `TestChildClass` a level up. You might use `class TestImplementation extends TestChildAbstractClass` and `abstract class TestChildAbstractClass extends TestRootAbstractClass<TestChildClass>` or something similar.

Comment: Answer accepted. In regard to the location of the constraint, for my specific use case, adding this at the `abstract class TestChildAbstractClass extends TestRootAbstractClass<TestChildClass>` level works best. However, I still can't shake the feeling that java expects a little too much here...it seems that by just implementing generics at `interface TestInterface<T extends TestRootClass>`, all ambiguity can be resolved. Anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class TestRootAbstractClass implements TestInterface {}
```

Because you had not specified a type parameter for `TestInterface`, the method in `TestRootAbstractClass` would have the following signature:

```
public abstract void test(TestRootClass extendedTestClass) throws Exception;
```

Because this method signature is not being overridden, it complains.

It looks like you will need to add type parameters to all of the relevant classes up the hierarchy in order for it to do what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

your interface TestInterface is generic; with generic type T extends TestRootClass. When you make a class implements them, you have 3 choices.

1)Lose genericity: java would resolve default as Object

```
public abstract class TestChildAbstractClass implements TestInterface {}
```

2)Keep Généricity. so your new class that implements interface should be généric to.

```
 public abstract class TestChildAbstractClass<P extends TestRootClass> implements TestInterface<P> {}
```

3)Spécify a généric type. so your new class has a généric type well defined:

```
public abstract class TestChildAbstractClass implements TestInterface<TestChildClass> {}
```